# Django - Why is my form invalid when a non-required field is not filled?

Tags: django

My form triggers form_invalid when the field "category" is empty.
The weird thing is, when the view displays, the "description" field does not have the asterisk indicating it's required, unlike "name" or "enabled", for instance. Also, when I try to send the form with an empty name, it correctly displays a little yellow mark and says "This field is required", but it doesn't say that when the category is empty.

So, it seems to correctly recognize that the category is not required, it just says it's invalid after I send the form.

My form looks like this:

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=80, required=True)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, required=False, label='Categoría')
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=False)
    price = forms.FloatField(required=True)
    image = forms.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, required=False)
    extras = forms.FileField(allow_empty_file=True, required=False)
    enabled = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].label = 'Nombre'
        self.fields['description'].label = 'Descripción'
        self.fields['price'].label = 'Precio'
        self.fields['image'].label = 'Imagen'
        self.fields['extras'].label = 'Extras'
        categories = Category.objects.filter(store=Profile.objects.get(user=user).store)
        if categories.count() == 0:
            self.fields['category'].required = False
        self.fields['category'].queryset = categories
        self.fields['enabled'].label = 'Habilitado'
```

It is included to my view in this way:

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'products/product_form.html'
    model = Product
    fields = ["name", "category", "description", "price", "image", "enabled", "extra"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("orders:products")
```

And my model looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name="products", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nombre")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Descripción", null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Precio")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", verbose_name="Imagen", null=True, blank=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Habilitado")
    extra = models.FileField(upload_to="media/files/", verbose_name="Extras", max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    detail_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: You never use the `ModelForm` you constructed. Django will create its own since nowhere you specify `form_class=...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use the `ModelForm` you constructed. Django will create its own since nowhere you specify [`form_class=…` [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class) in your `CreateView`. But that will not be sufficient, since Django will not pass a user by default. You will need to override the [**`.get_form_kwargs(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) as well to pass the user.

You also should make the `ProductForm` a `ModelForm`, since otherwise it has no `.save()` method:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    # …

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'description', 'price', 'image', 'enabled', 'extra']
```

In your view you thus specify the `form_class`, and override the `get_form_kwargs`, to inject the `user` in the `ModelForm` constructor:

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'products/product_form.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders:products')

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fk = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        fk['user'] = self.request.user
        return fk
```